# ¿Agregar parámetros a una url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Tengo la siguiente url

```
http://ejemplo.com/pagina?id=5
```

y tengo un href de la siguiente forma

```
<a href="?estado=Completado">Completado</a>
```

Cuando se le da clic al href la url queda

```
http://ejemplo.com/?estado=Completado
```

Pero lo que quiero que pase es que cuando yo de clik en el href la url quede y se haga el GET  a la url:

```
http://ejemplo.com/pagina?id=5&estado=Completado
```

Comment: hola, has intentado obtener la url, luego contatenarla y luego hacer `document.href=url`?

Comment: Esto parece más una algo a realizar al generar la página (y el enlace/botón) que algo que deba hacerse con JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin mas, este es el codigo que necesitas:

```js
$('#completado').on('click', function (){

 // Código alfa (para evaluar resultado en es.stackoverflow.com)
 this.href=window.location.href+"?id=5&"+this.href.split("?")[1];alert(this.href);

 // Código beta (para producción deberá funcionar en tu escenario)
 this.href=window.location.href+"&"+this.href.split("?")[1];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="completado" href="?estado=Completado">Completado</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como te pongo en un comentario, esto parece más una tarea a realizarse cuando se genera la página (y el enlace/botón) que con JavaScript una vez que la página ya se ha servido. Te voy a dejar un método para hacerlo con JavaScript

Para actualizar los valores de los enlaces, lo que podrías hacer es leer la URL (usando `window.location.href`), comprobar si tiene un signo de interrogación y añadir el nuevo parámetro de manera apropiada (si hay un signo quiere decir que hay más parámetros, por lo que el nuevo se debe añadir con un `&`, mientras que si no hay otros parámetros lo añadirás con un `?`).

Algo como esto:

```js
// leemos los enlaces, en tu caso deberás usar un selector más específico
var enlaces = document.querySelectorAll("a");
// leemos la dirección de la página y comprobamos si tiene ?
var url = window.location.href;
var conector = url.indexOf("?") < 0 ? "?" : "&";

// para cada enlace
for (var x = 0; x < enlaces.length; x++) {
  // reemplazamos su href por la URL + el parámetro con el conector correcto
  enlaces[x].href = url + enlaces[x].getAttribute("href").replace("?", conector);
}
```

```html
<a href="?estado=Completado">Completado</a>
<a href="?estado=Borrado">Borrado</a>
```

El ejemplo no se va a ver funcionando del todo bien en este snippet porque la URL no tiene ningún parámetro. Como nota: es importante que uses `.getAttribute("href")` en lugar de `.href` para leer el valor del `href` porque sino los navegadores leerán el valor completo del destino en lugar del valor textual, y puede generarte problemas a la hora de los reemplazos.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function $(elemento) {
  return document.querySelector(elemento);
}
$('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(window.location.href + '?estado=Completado');
  $('#btn').setAttribute('href', window.location.href + '?estado=Completado');
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Completado</button>
```

No se si te va a ayudar pero sirve si sabes js puro deje un alert para que te guies

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta.

Comment: *"No se si te va a ayudar"*. En ese caso creo no se debería responder para evitar confusión. Pronto tendrás suficiente reputación (50) para poder dejar comentarios en preguntas. Así podrás sugerir, preguntar, etc., antes de dar una respuesta concreta.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía, el ejemplo de Lias es aceptable (salvo un pequeño error que he corregido en mi respuesta a la pregunta), tal vez duda por estar iniciándose en stackoverflow... pronto lo veremos respondiendo sin titubear!! ;-))